# What is the best character considering the control in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe?

Tags: nintendo-switch, mario-kart-8-deluxe

After exhaustive testing of the characters, it was found that the characters that are smaller are the fastest. Baby Mario is an example of this.

However, he slides VERY on the track, making it impossible to run with him. So I would like to know a character that is fast but has the best control. I already tested Donk Kong and Bowser and they look good. But I would like to know with data which is the best.

Thank you!

Comment: If the test data was accurate, that would be very surprising as the games have stated since the first Mario Kart that larger/heavier characters are faster and lighter characters have better steering/handling capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After consulting the Mario Kart Wiki, it seems that by default, Baby Mario's Traction and Handling are actually very high. The smaller characters generally have the best steering abilities, but the slowest top speeds - I'm guessing that when you say they're the fastest, you mean you're able to set faster lap times with them. This, in my experience, is true in the 150cc and 200cc classes, where handling ability becomes critical. (Time Trial Mode is 150cc, if I recall correctly.)

I suspect that your choice of kart and/or wheels is hampering Baby Mario's Handling and/or Traction stats, perhaps in pursuit of some other stat like Top Speed. Speed is nothing without control! So before you try other characters, I would suggest [browsing the parts list](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_8_Deluxe#Parts.27_statistics) and trying to build a kart with better Handling and Traction, and see if that makes Baby Mario more easy to control.